# Create multiple actions in Struts2

Tags: struts2

How to create multiple actions in Struts2 in single action class?
Please give example ?
I found following code on searching internet but it is giving errors OR Do I need to write separate action class for every request ?

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you looked at the Apache Struts web site? You can reuse an action class between multiple actions by simply providing different mappings and those mappings can optionally specify methods other than the default "execute" so long as the signature is agreeable.

Comment: Active this type of question here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16505496/1490962

Answer (score 4):

Beside what @Quaternion said, S2 actions are in itself java class and i am not sure what you are asking (multiple actions in Struts2 in single action class).

We have several ways to use a single S2 action class here are few of them

Map single action class with different alias like.

```
<action name="A" class="MyActionClass">
  <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
  <result name="input">/Logon.jsp</result>
</action>


<action name="B" class="MyActionClass">
  <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
  <result name="input">/Logon.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But i believe you want to map different action request to different action method. S2 provides a way to define any number of methods and we can tell S2 to call which method on which action class from UI.

for e.g let's say we have a UserAction class which is responsible for handling user interaction like

1. Login
2. Logout
3. Registration

for this we need not to create different Action classes but we can create a single action class say UserAction and can define different methods in side it and can configure S2 to call different methods like

```
<action name="Logon" class="UserAction" method="logon">
  <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
  <result name="input">/Logon.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="Logout" class="UserAction" method="logout">
  <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
  <result name="input">/Logon.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="Register" class="tUserAction" methood="register">
  <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
  <result name="input">/Logon.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Hope this might help you to clear your doubts

In above use case `MyActionClass` has been mapped with two alias A and B and you can map to any number.

Answer (score 2):

**Another method:**

Here is the action class with 3 actions (execute, action1, action2)

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

   public String execute(){
     return SUCCESS;
   }

   public String action1(){
     return SUCCESS;
   }

   public String action2(){
     return SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

Here is config:

```
<action name="myAction" class="MyAction">
  <result>showMe.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">showMe.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Action "execute" will be called by default.
To call action "action1" or "action2" you must put parameter in your request whith name "method:action1" or "method:action2".

- **Call default action (execute):** /path_to_action/myAction.action
- **Call action1:** /path_to_action/myAction.action?method:action1
- **Call action2:** /path_to_action/myAction.action?method:action2

Your can change default method:

```
<action name="myAction" class="MyAction" method="action1">
  <result>showMe.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">showMe.jsp</result>
</action>
```

So, when your call /path_to_action/myAction.action, action1 will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

I got your question exactly that you want to write multiple redirects in single action based on action selected like add/edit/delete code at single place. You should look for [DispatchAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html) for your requirement.

Following are few examples you can look at, all provides how to implement DispatchAction.

[Link1](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-dispatch-action-example-1.html) 
[Link2](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-lookup-dispatch-action-example-1.html)
[Link3](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts-dispatch-action.shtml)

Comment: This is if you were using Struts1 while the OP specifically commented on Struts2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that crancran. You are free to add your own version of answer.